# how to cast my y.Value to List<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, casting

I want to cast `y.Value` to `List<Dictionary<string, object>`.

I tried:
`y.Value  as List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

But it will return `null`.

This is a my watch:

[image].

I don't know how to handle `object {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>}`.

thanks

Comment: Let's start with `y`, what is it? How have you initialized and filled it?

Comment: ur watch shows y.value as list of object. You need to cast y.value to List<object> then loop thru.. n cast each object as Dictionary<string,object>

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  `y` is `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y.Value` is a `List<object>` casted as an `object`, and those objects are eventually `Dictionary<string, object>`, although they are casted as object too. Your typing is not helpful here.

You can use LINQ to get the dictionaries out:

```
var list = ((IEnumerable<object>)y.Value)
           .Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
           .ToList();
```

Comment: I dont have a `Select` avaiable

Comment: You have to add a `using System.Linq;` on top of your file.

Comment: `y` is `System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>` does it make a difference ?

Comment: I get "'System.Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @kkkk00999 The problem is that `IEnumerable` doesn't support Linq. You can use `((IEnumerable)y.Value).Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>().ToList()` instead.

Comment: great you saved my day :)